# How add a new login to an existing SQL Server instance?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wix

I have made a bootstrapper-project with WiX 3.8 which installs - among others - SQL Server Express 2012.
By that installation a SQL Server instance - called "SQLEXPRESS" - is created.
Further i create a new local user (if necessary) and let it be a member of the administrators group.

Now i need to create in that SQL Server instance a new login (either with WiX (but i don't want to create a database at that point of time) or C#) with the existing user.

How can this be done?